# Failing getting device UUID from capacitor/device on Android

Tags: android, json, angular, typescript, capacitor

I am trying to get my devices UUID so that I can send a notification to a specific device over Firebase using the Device UUID. I have my front end and back end connected so that the back end can send a notification to my front end using Firebase. While trying to get the device UUID, all I get is a 16 character value with numbers and words.

---

These are my dependencies inside `package.json`

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^15.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "^15.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^15.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^15.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^15.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^15.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^15.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^15.2.0",
    "@capacitor/android": "^4.1.0",
    "@capacitor/core": "^4.1.0",
    "@capacitor/device": "^4.1.0",
    "@capacitor/ios": "^4.1.0",
    "device-uuid": "^1.0.4",
    "primeicons": "^6.0.1",
    "primeng": "^15.2.0",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.12.0"
  },
```

I am using capacitor/device in order to get the UUID.

---

This is my code that is inside the `app.component.ts` where I try to get the device UUID.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { Device } from '@capacitor/device';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title!: string;

  checked: boolean = false;
  deviceId: any;
  result: any;
  platform: any;
  info: any;

  constructor (private appService: AppService) {}

  sendNotification () {
    Device.getInfo().then((info) => {
      this.info = info
      this.platform = info.platform
      Device.getId().then((deviceId) => {
        this.deviceId = deviceId.uuid
        this.result = this.appService.sendNotification(this.platform, this.deviceId);
      })
    })
  }
}
```

I have a button on the application where when it's clicked it is supposed to show the device UUID and the device info but from this code, all I get from my device is a 16 character value like (9c08a2578a6475d9) which I don't know what this value is.

**Can someone help me on how can I get the 36 character UUID from my device?**

**Also, what is the 16 character value that I am retrieving if is not the device UUID?**

I have tried searching on the web and also browsed similar stackoverflow questions like [Best possible way to get device Id in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60503568/best-possible-way-to-get-device-id-in-android), [how can I get a unique device ID in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49692073/how-can-i-get-a-unique-device-id-in-javascript), [Unique ID of Android device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4468248/unique-id-of-android-device) but none of these seem to work for me since I'm using a different approach to this. I have also used both android emulators and physical android devices, but the result is always the same.

Answer (score 0):

the capacitor device UUID is not the id which we use for sending the push notifications
the Capacitor Device UUID changes for every app install from app store.

the device id you are looking for is fcm id which firebase provide  to the users
if you are building an ios web app you can use the apn and for android web app you can use the fcm

in android the firebase gives a fcm token to every user,  the token may change for every reinstall of the app so whenever user opens the app try to update the token and get with the fcms /apns , they have their own methods to get the token

when user has a token we can send them notifications
first try the test notification from firebase's test push notification option of the official site