# how to retrieve unique identifiers from android 11 r (API 30) device?

Tags: java, android, uniqueidentifier, mac-address, imei

I want to get unique identifiers like Android Device ID, IMEI, or MAC address from an Android phone with Android version 11 using Java.
Can someone help? I need just either one unique identifier.
This is the code that I use to get IMEI:

```
public String getIMEI() {
        Context context = null;
        TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        Log.i("Testing: ", telephonyManager.getImei());
        return telephonyManager.getImei();
}
```

And this is the error message that I got:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object android.content.Context.getSystemService(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
```

Comment: Is your issue specific to android R? Are you able to extract unique ID for other android versions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Best possible way to get device Id in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60503568/best-possible-way-to-get-device-id-in-android)

Comment: @Kartoos I successfully retrieved unique ID from Android 7 before. However, that particular code is not suitable to use for Android 11.

Comment: When you say code is not suitable, what is the issue? Are you getting errors? Or some other problem?

Comment: @Kartoos Yes, keep getting error as it always retrieves null

Comment: I'll add my code and the error message.

Comment: `Context context = null;` You are just setting the `context` to null prior to first use. Does this make sense?

Comment: If you use this method within an `Activity` derived class just use `getSystemService()` method without `context` in the beginning. Or in a fragment derived class use `reqiureContext().getSystemService()` method.

Answer (score 1):

As of the API 29, Google introduced new security policies to the [`TelephonyManager.getImei`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager#getImei(int)) API. So it won't be available for 3rd party apps for security reasons.
Look at what is mentioned in the API's description:

> Starting with API level 29, persistent device identifiers are guarded behind additional restrictions, and apps are recommended to use resettable identifiers (see [Best practices for unique identifiers](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids)). This method can be invoked if one of the following requirements is met:
>
> - If the calling app has been granted the READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE permission; this is a privileged permission that can only be granted to apps preloaded on the device.
> - If the calling app is the device owner of a fully-managed device, a profile owner of an organization-owned device, or their delegates (see [DevicePolicyManager.getEnrollmentSpecificId()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager#getEnrollmentSpecificId())).
> - If the calling app has carrier privileges (see [hasCarrierPrivileges()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager#hasCarrierPrivileges())) on any active subscription.
> - If the calling app is the default SMS role holder (see [RoleManager.isRoleHeld(java.lang.String)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager#hasCarrierPrivileges())).
> - If the calling app has been granted the [Manifest.permission#USE_ICC_AUTH_WITH_DEVICE_IDENTIFIER](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#USE_ICC_AUTH_WITH_DEVICE_IDENTIFIER) permission.